# How to change string case in NIM?

Tags: nim-lang, tolower

In NIM 0.17 `toLower is deprecated`.
So, what would be the proper way of changing the case of a string in NIM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strutils.toLowerAscii` or `unicode.toLower` depending on which you want.